# Can a connectionId be a part of multiple groups in hub class

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Can I call `Groups.Add` on the same connectionid but for 2 different groups and if i broadcast a certain message to either group the connectionid added will get both messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is exactly what JabbR, the flagship test application for SignalR, does. It uses groups to represent "rooms" and, in JabbR, a user can be in *N* rooms. You can see the exact details of that implementation [here](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/Hubs/Chat.cs#L578).